# My BYOD application says Application Access Denied The device has been jailbroken

Tags: blackberry

After upgrading my android device to Android 11, I am UNABLE to activate my enterprise BYOD app using UEM Client app. **It says Application Access Denied The device has been jailbroken.**

However, on the same device I am able to activate and use Blackberry Work, Edit, etc without any issues

Has anyone come across such issue and fix for it?

**Details:**
Google Pixel 2XL, Android 11
Blackberry Dynamics SDK 6.0.1.83

Answer (score 1):

BlackBerry Dynamics SDK version 6.0 does not support Android 11.  To resolve this issue, upgrade to BlackBerry Dynamics SDK version 8.1, which does support Android 11.  You can download it from here:  https://developers.blackberry.com/us/en/resources/downloads.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am able to activate and use debug build of same app on Android 11. Is there anything related to release build ?

Comment: Some Android APIs the BD SDK uses for root device detection were changed in Android 11. BD SDK 8.1 was updated to support this change.